# cython is not compiled properly with openmp

Tags: python, mingw, openmp, cython

I am running a setup for cython using:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("par4",
              ["par4.pyx"],
              extra_compile_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-march=native", "-fopenmp" ],
              extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']
              ) 
]

setup( 
  name = "par4",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

But I got this in the setup:

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
```

It means somehow, it cannot see the openmp option. NB: I am using windows with `mingw32`, and I have installed in `mingw32-base, mingw32-gcc=g++, msys-base.` I have additionally installed `mingw32-pthreads-w32 (dev), mingw32-pthreads-w32 (doc), mingw32-pthreads-w32 (lic)` as I have read from other post, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "I am using windows with mingw32" - **you're not**. `cl` is MSVC.

Comment: I am not quite understand what you mean, beside I am beginner in programming. If you mean the command line, I am using the command prompt with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Comment: The compiler for microsoft visual C is called `cl`. Therefore the error message `cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'` tells me that microsoft visual C is complaining that it doesn't understand the option `-fopenmp`. Therefore you are not using mingw

Comment: On the basis that you're using MSVC (and that MSVC is a much better choice than MinGW for Cython on Windows) why don't you use `/openmp` instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=msvc-170)

Comment: I have used `-openmp`, and it worked. Thanks for the discussion.